# Why is this function's argument not being invoked as a function?

Tags: go

Here is the complete example from my current reading material "Hands-On Restful Web Services With Go" from Packt.

```
func filterContentType(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Currently in the check content type middleware")
        // Filtering requests by MIME type
        if r.Header.Get("Content-type") != "application/json" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType)
            w.Write([]byte("415 - Unsupported Media Type. Please send JSON"))
            return
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func setServerTimeCookie(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Setting cookie to every API response
        cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "ServerTimeUTC", Value: strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)}
        http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
        log.Println("Currently in the set server time middleware")
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Check if method is POST
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        var tempCity city
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        err := decoder.Decode(&tempCity)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer r.Body.Close()
        // Your resource creation logic goes here. For now it is plain print to console
        log.Printf("Got %s city with area of %d sq miles!\n", tempCity.Name, tempCity.Area)
        // Tell everything is fine
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte("201 - Created"))
    } else {
        // Say method not allowed
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        w.Write([]byte("405 - Method Not Allowed"))
    }
}

func main() {
    originalHandler := http.HandlerFunc(handle)
    http.Handle("/city", filterContentType(setServerTimeCookie(originalHandler)))  // !
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

This program simply consists of the main function and 3 other functions, their logic is arbitrary and just copied from my book's example.

At bottom, where I've commented with *"!"*, `filterContentType` is using an argument that itself is a function (`setServerTimeCookie`), and it looks like it's being invoked with `originalHandler` as its argument.

However when this code is run, the order of execution is:

1. `filterContentType` 2. `setServerTimeCookie` 3. `originalHandler`

This is counterintuitive to what I understand about using functions as arguments. I assumed that `setServerTimeCookie` would be the first to execute but that's not the case; it's behaving like an uninvoked function.

This leads to my question, what is causing `setServerTimeCookie` to defer its execution despite the syntax suggesting it's being invoked as `filterContentType`'s argument?

I attempted to simplify things for my own understanding:

```
func main() {

    one(two(three))
}

func one(f func()) {
    fmt.Println("ONE\n")
    f()
}

func two(f func()) {
    fmt.Println("TWO\n")
    f()
}

func three(){
    fmt.Println("THREE\n")
}
```

This code does not build, I'm left with the error:
`two(three) used as value` -which tells me that `two` is being invoked, unlike the book's example.

What's the difference and again, why doesn't the book's example invoke `setServerTimeCookie` first? My only assumption is that it has something to do with the implementation of `http.HandlerFunc` so maybe I should start there.

Any insight to fast-forward my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [doesn't compile](https://go.dev/play/p/uEkw5tD6XIR) because `two(three)` does not return a value.

I assume you want to return a function closure in this case, so to fix:

```
func two(f func()) func() {
    return func() {
        fmt.Println("TWO\n")
        f()
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/vBrAO6nwy4X

---

Circling back to your question about `setServerTimeCookie` and it's use of `return http.HandlerFunc(fn)`. Looking at the source for [http.HandlerFunc](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/net/http/server.go;l=2105) reveals it's actually a type definition - and *NOT* a conventional function call. It's actual IMHO the most powerful and underrated four lines of code in the `go` standard library:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

By creating this value of `http.HandlerFunc`, it's implicitly a `http.Handler`, since it provides the `ServeHTTP` method. This therefore allows this method to be called *upon request* - which is exactly what a webservice is designed to do: the underlying function `f` will be invoked when the handler is invoked.

Comment: Brilliant answer. That was exactly the info I needed and also confirmed my intuition, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because in the expression `one(two(three))` function `two` is not passed as function reference. Instead function `two` is called with the argument `tree`, which is not what function `one` expects